# Injecting Google recaptcha's JS file in a chrome extension's content.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

New to chrome extensions and have the following issue:

I am trying to display recaptcha in my content script. As you know, it needs to include this `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>` tag, and since content scripts run in an isolated environment, I cannot just add it via

```
   const script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = 'https://...';
   // ...and so on
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script) accepted answer, however, illustrates a great way of script injection into a content script, but only for local files. So is there any way to include a script from a CDN?

Comment: DOM script element runs in page environment, not in isolated world.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

```
var apiScript = document.createElement('script');  
apiScript.setAttribute('src','insert source here');
document.head.appendChild(apiScript);
```